# Access all stored cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome, console, local

I want to access my Chrome stored cookies from the JavaScript console. Is this possible?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 35):

If you only need the cookies for the active site: Have a look at `document.cookie`. It contains semicolon-separated `key=value` pairs.

Edit: Note that due to security concerns you can't access cookies from a different domain. When you run something from the console, it's the equivalent of it running directly from the page, so since they don't want a spam site getting your Facebook credentials, you'll have to go to each website separately.

Comment: Does not work. Always prints undefined despite cookies being shown in BrowserDevtools > Application (Chrome)

Answer (score 25):

Easiest way to go:

```
console.log(document.cookie);
```

Comment: always prints undefined despite cookies being shown in BrowserDevtools > Application

Comment: @Phil, can you provide example of page, what the console prints and what do you need to see instead? Maybe the answer can be improved. On my webs, I usually see what I need to see.

Comment: @Phil I m having same issue. I am able to see cookie in BrowserDevtools > Application > Storage > Cookie. But i when i try to access it by document.cookie i get undefined. how did you resolve this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using Chrome, if you have the possibility to use other tool instead of only the Console, you can access all stored cookies and see detailed information using the tab "Resources". To do this:

- Open Developer Tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>)
- Click on "Resources" tab
- Expand the "Cookies" list item
- Click on the website address